# Gamecube Memory Cards Life Span

Tags: nintendo-gamecube

It's getting to that time where cartridge based hardware such as Nintendo Gameboy cartridges are losing their saved data due to the internal batteries dying.

I was wondering if this applies to Gamecube memory cards too?

I have an Animal Crossing save where I managed to collect all the NES games and I really don't want to lose it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's no battery in a memory card, so you should be good to go until bit rot inevitably occurs after some decades - but I'm not sure of the exact techonology, and I'm not able to open one of my own memory cards right now. Find a way to run homebrew on a Wii or GameCube and make backups if you want to be absolutely certain you won't ever lose it.

Comment: Homebrewing a Wii is pretty easy--especially if, like me you got a Wii U so the Wii is just collecting dust. I managed to get all my GC saves off with little trouble

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A GameCube memory card is [nothing more than a modified SD card](http://ngc.scorpei.com/GUIDE-SD_adapter.html) in nature. There is no battery built in, so it will not expire in a similar manner to old cartridge games.